# "is" vs. "has been"

Tags: meaning, tense

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning?

> This album is different from the rest of their albums in the way that a whole new sound **is** incorporated into it.
>
> This album is different from the rest of their albums in the way that a whole new sound **has been** incorporated into it.

Comment: If the album is recently released, use *has been...*

Answer (score 1):

I think both sentences are grammatical, but  the second one is better because it explains what has been done (reason ) to make the album special (result). The first sentence just describes the state of things.